# Kotlin Spring boot Jackson deserialization

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I want to deserialize receiving string into my entity but i have this exception:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `fonbet.parser.models.childs.AllScore` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
What am i doing wrong? What object should i have to deserialize this json?

I receive Json string with object inside it:

```
"liveEventInfos": [
    {
      "eventId": 42183931,
      "timer": "45:00",
      "timerSeconds": 2700,
      "timerDirection": 0,
      "scoreFunction": "Football",
      "scoreComment": "(1-2) https://www.youtube.com/watch v=TDkuCAfGoLg",
      "scoreCommentTail": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDkuCAfGoLg",
      "scores": [
        [
          {
            "c1": "1",
            "c2": "2"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "c1": "1",
            "c2": "2",
            "title": "тайм"
          },
          {
            "c1": "0",
            "c2": "0",
            "title": "тайм"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "subscores": []
    } 
]
```

What i have:

I have entity for this json part:

```
data class LiveEventInfo(
    var eventId: Long?,
    var timer: String?,
    var timerSeconds: Long?,
    var timerDirection: Long?,
    var scoreFunction: String?,
    var scoreComment: String?,
    var scoreCommentTail: String?,
    var scores: List<AllScore>?
)
```

and AllScore:

```
data class AllScore(
    val matchSore: HashMap<String, String>,
    val timeScore: HashMap<String, String>
)
```

Comment: I think AllScore class should have only `c1`, `c2` and optional `title` String properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

1. `AllScore` is an object with 2 fields `matchSore`, `timeScore` which are NOT referenced in the JSON.
2. JSON stream has 1 or 2 arrays within the outer array under the node `scores`.  How should the parse deserialize this?  Is the first `matchSore`? and if two then it is `matchSore` and `timeScore` ?
3. You are missing `subscores`
4. The JSON you provide is missing the outer `{` `}`
5. Normally you should have a wrapper object to read in to in a case like this.

The following code works, you should be able to get something working from this point:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val json ="""
    {
        "liveEventInfos": [
        {
          "eventId": 42183931,
          "timer": "45:00",
          "timerSeconds": 2700,
          "timerDirection": 0,
          "scoreFunction": "Football",
          "scoreComment": "(1-2) https://www.youtube.com/watch v=TDkuCAfGoLg",
          "scoreCommentTail": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDkuCAfGoLg",
          "scores": [
            [
              {
                "c1": "1",
                "c2": "2"
              }
            ],
            [
              {
                "c1": "1",
                "c2": "2",
                "title": "тайм"
              },
              {
                "c1": "0",
                "c2": "0",
                "title": "тайм"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "subscores": []
        } 
    ]
    }
    """.trimIndent()

    val mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .addModule(KotlinModule.Builder().configure(KotlinFeature.StrictNullChecks, true).build())
        .build()
    val parsed = mapper.readValue(json, LiveEventInfos::class.java)
    println(parsed)
}

data class LiveEventInfos(
    val liveEventInfos: List<LiveEventInfo>
)

data class LiveEventInfo(
    var eventId: Long?,
    var timer: String?,
    var timerSeconds: Long?,
    var timerDirection: Long?,
    var scoreFunction: String?,
    var scoreComment: String?,
    var scoreCommentTail: String?,
    var scores: List<List<Map<String, String>>>?,
    val subscores: List<Any>?,
)
```